# Why is type(((),)[0]) a tuple and not an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this code showing the type of a ***tuple*** and not of an ***int***?

```
type(((),)[0])
```

Comment: Because `()` is a tuple?

Comment: what is your exact problem?

Comment: `((),)` is a tuple containing `()`. The first element of `((),)` is given by `((),)[0]`.

Comment: What argument led you to believe it would be int, or *anything* other than tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `((),)[0]` is equivalent to `()` (read up python please) which is a tuple, not an int.